# Quick way to open file in Sublime search results

Tags: macos, search, terminal, sublimetext2

I often use Sublime text's fantastic "search all open files/folders" feature (CMD+SHIFT+F).

However- it is slow and impractical to navigate to each file in my file explorer/browser (I'm on OSX).

Is there a way to open the file directly from the results (or in a quicker way some how)?

Below is a screenshot to explain:

[image: content-top clearfix]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Double click on the file path in the results buffer
- Double click on a specific line of the result to jump straight to that line

Comment: Thanks! How would I search inside of just the files in the results?

Comment: @Ycon : Ask that as a new question.  I have an answer, but I need some space & image capabilities to write it out.